# Telend ESB unique message id

Tags: http, message, esb, talend

I search Talend documentation, but maybe I overlook something. I have route that receive http request and I want to get that request message ID. Maybe it is in some property, but how I can get it? It can't be so difficult than WSO2 or Mule.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at the Camel documentation instead :
http://camel.apache.org/simple.html

${id} will give you the ID that Camel has given to the incoming message